# Spring: How does a request scoped bean behave inside a asynchronus method call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous, requestscope

Im working with Spring Boot 2.2.4.

I have the following class, where Client is a request scoped bean:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
public class CacheLoader {

  private Client client;

  @Async
  public void load() {
    //do something else
    client.execute();
  }
}
```

The load method is called in a controller. The request is finished before the execute() method starts in the other thread spawned by the async load() method.

Still the execute method does finish successfully. Why is the request Scoped bean still available even though the request was finished before?

Also was is going to happen if two requests are send. Will the Client which is bound to the second request replace the Client from the first request so that the asynchronous method triggered by the first request will execute the call with the Client from the second request?

Comment: Are you sure it executes asyn? Only the annotation isn't enough (you also need `@EnableAsync` in your configuration. A request scoped bean will not replace another (else it would be a pretty useless thing to have wouldn't it).

Comment: @M.Deinum
I think so. 
I stopped in the load method via debugging but the controller response was send to the frontend.

Comment: Well it might work, incidentally but don't count on it. A request scoped bean is destroyed after the request is finished. Could be that the scope is still alive when the method is executed, but I would stronglu suggest not to count on it.

Comment: a request scoped bean is usually stored in the threadlocal object of the executing thread. So im not sure of the implementation but i would guess that the request scoped bean will transfer its data to the new threads threadlocal storage.

Comment: The project has an implementation of the PoolExecutor which passes the request scoped bean to the task running in the other thread.
I overlooked that.